# How to override constraints that are set in parent class

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a parent class that simply is a UIStackView with a couple other generic properties that will be used throughout the app.

```
class baseStackView:UIView {
var stack: UIStackView
init(_ coder: NSCoder? = nil) {

    stack = UIStackView()
    stack.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    stack.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fill
    stack.spacing = 20

    if let coder = coder {
        super.init(coder: coder)!
    } else {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    addSubview(stackView)
}

}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    setupConstraints()
}

private func setupConstraints() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

    stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
    stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
}
```

Now, i have come to a situation where i need to change the leading and trailing anchors of the stackView to change fit the look of one of my required views.

So naturally, i simply set the trailing, leading constraints again in one of my child classes.

```
var baseView: BaseStackView
baseView = BaseStackView()
baseView.stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
baseView.stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
baseView.stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

This seems to cause conflict within my constraints as technically i am setting it twice. Is there a way to override the initial constraints to avoid these warning? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create new constraints. Control-drag from the constraints that you want to change into your class's source file to create outlets to the constraints.

You can then change the constant value on the constraints to change their amounts.

Comment: Im not using the storyboard. Is there a way to replicate this through code?

Comment: Sure. Keep instance variables to the constraints when you set them up, using meaningful names. (The code you posted create constraints with "set and forget" syntax that doesn't save them. Instead of doing that, assign the results of  a line like `baseView.stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor)` to an instance variable.

Comment: Then set isActive to true in a second line of code.